# Reactivating a cancelled campaign

Tags: campaign

I have a Salesforce Campaign which is cancelled. I haven't really worked with Campaigns before much, so I have no idea how to reactivate the campaign, as there is no edit button or similar on the detail page[image].

Tia.

Comment: I guess it's a different page layout having all the buttons removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the edit -ability for system admin was switched off :)

Comment: You may want to add a bit more detail to your answer to possibly help others that run into a similar problem.

Comment: Well, the system admin profile did not have edit ability for this object. That was the problem. I don't know how to be more specific about this. I hope this is clear enough?